# How can I copy paste from EMACS [terminal mode] to another application without MOUSE?

Tags: emacs

I use GNU Emacs 25.1.1. I use it in terminal mode. 
In GUI Mode I know how to copy and yank. In terminal mode, copying and pasting from another application works but not the usual keybinding.

Usually **C-y** is for yank inside emacs but in my terminal mode **C-Shift-V** only works for yanking.

But when I try to copy from emacs to another shell or application it doesn't copy.

I don't want to use mouse for copying and yanking.. 
Is there any workaround? What Am I doing Wrong?

Answer (score 4):

In "terminal mode", you're not really interacting with emacs. You're interacting with your terminal or terminal emulator.

When you `copy` and `paste` text, the terminal does it : you're taking the text that the terminal displays and not the text that is in your emacs app.

That's why you have to use terminal keybindings : **Ctrl-Shift-C** and **Ctrl-Shift-V** to copy and paste text.

That's also why pasting large text through terminal in emacs is slow : the terminal "get" the text and "redirect" it to emacs.

So, if you want to select, copy and paste text without the mouse, you'll have to configure your terminal.

[Here's an example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/302263/selecting-text-in-the-terminal-without-using-the-mouse)

Comment: What do you mean "Your" terminal? This is a terminal written in elisp, no? So I don't know why we would have C-S C and C-S-V. They don't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 4):

You might like to try `xclip-mode` (available from GNU ELPA), which relies on externals programs (`xclip` under X11, and `pbcopy` on macOS) to let Emacs communicate with your GUI (for things like <kbd>C-y</kbd> and <kbd>C-k</kbd>) even though it's running inside a text terminal.

Comment: If X11 is not on, enables `xclip-mode` leads few seconds slowness to paste operation, is it possible ot prevent it in case automatically disable it?

Comment: @alper" This seems out of topic.  Please make a bug report instead.

Answer (score 2):

There is a package called [`clipetty`](https://github.com/spudlyo/clipetty) to manipulate the system clipboard with emacs from a tty.

Config it is simple, add following two lines to your init file.

```lisp
(require 'clipetty)
(global-clipetty-mode)
```

Then every time you kill or yank something, your system clipboard is also overwritten.

To paste to emacs, you can use terminal keybindings <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-V</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

I do this by using `shell-command-on-region` along with the command-line `pbpaste`/`pbcopy` on my macOS box. Bind it to a key if necessary:

```
(global-set-key "\C-cr" (shell-command-on-region (point) (mark) "pbcopy"))
```

There are similar command-line programs you can use for Windows (https://github.com/ghuntley/pasteboard) and Linux (`xsel`/`xclip`).